# Difference between different ways to call static method from within class

Tags: python

Is there a difference in the two ways of calling a static method in the same class shown below?

```
class MyClass:

  def __init__(self):
    self.do_something() #or MyClass.do_something()?

  @staticmethod
  def do_something():
    pass
```

More specifically, particularly in the cases of refactoring (changing class name) and inheritance (as static methods can be inherited and overridden in Python)?

Comment: In java, the (strong) convention is to avoid using "this" in a static context.  Of course static methods are so rare in python (module-level functions are just better most of the time) so either is fine really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: sorry but it *does* matter, cf jonrsharpe's answer.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, realising that the question was a **little** more narrow than the title and first sentence-fragment, but could it be rewritten to promote the differences-angle instead?

Comment: It is absolutely not the same thing ! In Python you can have static method inheritance that effectively does not exist in Java, but Python is not Java. IMHO, the best idiom would be `__class__.do_something()` because it can also be used for class data.

Comment: More exactly, best idioms are `__class__.do_something()` uses the staticmethod in same class (but allows easy refactoring) and `self.__class__.do_something()` uses the potentially overriden method.  Both can be used with data with same differences.

Comment: Well, I got a good answer from @jonrsharpe, so I am happy regardless whether the question remains closed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only think of one situation in which it would make a difference; what about when you inherit from `MyClass`? Compare:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.do_something()
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print "Base class"


>>> class SubClass(MyClass):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print "Sub class"


>>> s = SubClass()
Sub class
```

with:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass.do_something()
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print "Base class"


>>> class SubClass(MyClass):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print "Sub class"


>>> s = SubClass()
Base class
```

This is a contrived example, but you should consider what you think the appropriate behaviour should be.

---

Your example of refactoring to change the class name is a good one, too; `self` doesn't have to be updated whenever you rename the class, whereas if you have explicit `MyClass` references you have to update them all (a good IDE will do this for you, but if you can avoid it that's better).

Comment: I didn't know that static methods were inherited in python. Then there actually is a difference other than semantical. Thanks for the example.